# anillo noetheriano y de generación finita.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Sea $A=\oplus{A_i}$, $i\geq{0}$ anillo graduado.

Si $A$ es anillo noetheriano entonces $A_0$ es noetheriano y $A$ es de generación finita como $A_0$-álgebra.

Dm:

Defino $I=\oplus{A_i}$ donde $i\geq{1}$, probé que $I$ es ideal de $A$.

Ahora defino $F:A\longrightarrow{A_0}$ tal que $F(a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_d)=a_0$ vemos que es un epimorfismo de anillos y que el $ \ker(F)=I$. Luego por primer teo. de isomorfismo $\displaystyle A/I\simeq{A_0}$ y como A noetheriano entonces el cociente es noetheriano y luego $A_0$ noetheriano. Ya esta la primera parte.

Para la segunda parte como $I$ es ideal de $A $ y $A$ es noetheriano entonces $I$ es de generación finita. Entonces $I=\langle f_1,...,f_k\rangle$ donde los $f_i $ son elementos homogéneos de $A$.

Afirmación:

> Para todo elemento $f\in{A}$ tenemos que existen $r_1,...,r_k\in{A_0}$ tal que $f=r_1f_1+\cdots+r_kf_k$.

Esa afirmación quiere decir que $A$ es de generación finita como $A_0$-álgebra??

Si es así, quisiera una sugerencia por favor.

---

English translation:

Let $A= \bigoplus_{i\ge 0} A_i$ be a graded ring.

If $A$ is a Noetherian ring then $A_0$ is Noetherian and is finitely generated as an $A_0$-algebra.

Proof:
Define $I = \bigoplus_{i\ge 1} A_i$, then $I$ is an ideal of $A$.

Now, define $F: A\to A_0$ so that $F(a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_d) = a_0$, we see that $F$ is an epimorphism of rings and $\ker F = I$. Then by the first isomorphism theorem $A/I \cong A_0$ and since $A$ is Noetherian, the quotient is Noetherian and thus $A_0$ is Noetherian.

For the second part, since $I$ is an ideal of $A$ and $A$ is Noetherian, $I$ is finitely generated. Thus, $I = \langle f_1, \ldots, f_k \rangle$ where the $f_i$ are homogeneous elements of $A$.

Claim:

> For each element $f\in A$, there exist $r_i \in A_0$ such that $f = r_1f_1 +\ldots + r_kf_k$.

Does this claim imply that $A$ is finitely generated as an $A_0$ algebra? If so, I would like a hint, please.

Comment: Please keep the discussion about language requirements to Meta.

Comment: Some of those comments were quite relevant to the topic, and now you deleted the link to the meta discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is wrong: in $A=K[X]$ we have $I=(X)$ and $A\ne KX$.

The correct claim is $A=A_0[f_1,\dots,f_k]$.

Comment: @marquinho See the Proposition 10.7 from Atiyah and Macdonald.